# Where to find current standalone configuration?

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

I have a fully working JBoss 6.3.3.GA instance but one of my colleagues unwittingly connected to my Development server instead of his, and updated my `Standalone.xml` file. 
He made a lot of changes and there's no way (at least I didn't find any one) to get my old file back.

Now I need to restart my server, and I'm afraid I'll loose my current configuration forever since his update will be taken into account.

My question is : Is there anyway I can find my current XML Standalone configuration in any temporary folder or something like that ?

Answer (score 2):

Under your jboss directory go to : standalone/configuration/standalone_xml_history.
You should find different versions : standalone.boot.xml, standalone.initial.xml, standalone.last.xml ... etc
You will also find old configurations of your standalone stored in folders which names include  the date when you made those configurations includig a folder containing your current configuration.